# Show individual database record based on the given id

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, search, show

### I still can't get it to work it's a bit tricky for me as a codeigniter newbie. please help me.

I am working with codeigniter and now i want to show my factories one by one.

I made a search function where i can search my factories. i show the results in a html table.

Now i want to create a hyperlink for the factory name.  So when i click on the factory name a page will open with all the information about that specific factory.

I hope someone knows what i mean.

my searchview:

```
<div id="bigcontent">
<h1>Bedrijven zoeken</h1>
<br />
<form name="input" action="searchresults" method="post">
<input type="search" placeholder="Zoeken..." name="search">
<input type="submit" value="Zoeken" class="searchbutton">
</form>

<br /><br />
<form method="link" action="<?php echo base_url('home/bedrijven')?>">
<input type="submit" value="Bedrijven">
</form>
</div>
```

Searchresults:

```
<div id="bigcontent">
<h2>Zoekresultaten:</h2>
<br /> <br />
<table>
<tr><th>Bedrijf</th><th>Adres</th><th>Postcode</th><th>Plaats</th><th>Website</th><th>Email</th></tr>
<hr>
<br /> <br />

<?php foreach($query as $item):?>
<tr>
<td><a href="<?php echo base_url('home/showindividueel')?>"><?= $item->Bedrijfsnaam ?></td>
<td><?= $item->Adres ?></td>
<td><?= $item->Postcode ?></td>
<td><?= $item->Plaats ?></td>
<td><?= $item->Website ?></td>
<td><?= $item->Email ?></td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach;?>

</table>

<br /> <br />
<hr>
<br />
<<<a href="<?php echo base_url('home/search') ?>">Terug</a>
</div>
```

Search controller:

```
function search()
{
    $this->load->view('header');
    $this->load->view('search');
    $this->load->view('footer');
}

function searchresults()
{
    $match = $this->input->post('search');
    $data['query'] = $this->bedrijven_model->get_search($match);
    $this->load->view('header');
    $this->load->view('searchresults', $data);
    $this->load->view('footer');
}
```

searchmodel:

```
function get_search($match)
{
    $this->db->like('Bedrijfsnaam', $match);
    $this->db->or_like('Postcode', $match);
    $this->db->or_like('Plaats', $match);
    $this->db->or_like('Telefoonnummer', $match);
    $this->db->or_like('Email', $match);
    $this->db->or_like('Website', $match);
    $this->db->or_like('Profiel', $match);
    $this->db->or_like('Adres', $match);
    $query = $this->db->get('bedrijven');

    return $query->result();
}
```

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code into your **Searchresults** and replace these lines to yours.

```
 <?php foreach($query as $item):?>
 <tr>
  <td><a href="<?php echo base_url()?>'home/showindividueel/<?php echo $item->idbedrijven?>'"><?= $item->Bedrijfsnaam   ?></td>
   <td><?= $item->Adres ?></td>
    <td><?= $item->Postcode ?></td>
    <td><?= $item->Plaats ?></td>
    <td><?= $item->Website ?></td>
     <td><?= $item->Email ?></td>
     </tr>
 <?php endforeach;?>
```

then make a showindividueel function into your home controller

```
      function showindividueel($id)
      {
           $data['query'] = $this->bedrijven_model->get_result($id);
           $this-load->view('table_individual',$data);
      }
```

this is your model code

```
     function get_result($id);
     {
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('bedrijven');

        $this->db->where('idbedrijven', $id);
        $result = $this->db->get();
        return $result->result();   
     }
```

then make view **table_individual.php** and paste this code

```
       <table>
       <tr><th>Adres</th><th>Postcode</th><th>Plaats</th><th>Website</th><th>Email</th></tr>
<hr>
<br /> <br />

 <?php foreach($query as $item):?>
   <tr>

 <td><?= $item->Adres ?></td>
 <td><?= $item->Postcode ?></td>
 <td><?= $item->Plaats ?></td>
 <td><?= $item->Website ?></td>
 <td><?= $item->Email ?></td>
 </tr>
 <?php endforeach;?>

  </table>
```

### UPDATED

Comment: Allright could you explain this a bit more? what exactly do i have to  put in the controller function to really show by id?

Comment: okay. i really can't get it to work. i forgot to tell that i'm new to codeigniter. but i can't figure it out. could you help me please?

Comment: what u r missing or facing problem

Comment: the model and the link in the views. i don't know what do put in my model and in my controller to get that link working because it does not work now.

Comment: is there any bedrijvenid field

Comment: it's called idbedrijven. that's the main id of the table

Comment: what is your auto increment/ primary key field name in table bedrijven?

Comment: i have update code now do it as i  told in code if u find any problem then told me i m here for ur help

Comment: i get a server error now i can't see the error in the logfile because it has something to do with the controller EDIT found the errror. you missed a > in the controller code

Comment: when i click on a link in the table on searchresults i get an 404 not found page on this url http://kees.een-site-bouwen.nl/'home/showindividueel/1'

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26140/discussion-between-kees-sonnema-and-azam-alvi)